# Simple problem involving an integral returns the error message NIntegrate::inumr

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I am trying to solve the function below for values of y of 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, and 3.

This is how I defined the function:

```
f[y_]:=1-0.484*Integrate[E^(-x)Sinh[Sqrt[2x]],{x, 0, y}]
```

When I input f[0.5] I receive an output with the definite integral in terms of x written out but not solved. When I attempt to solve for a numerical answer I get the error message NIntegrate::inumr NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand E^-x sinh[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x]] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,0.5}}.

Is this a syntax error on my part? How should I go about fixing this error?
Thank you in advance for any responses.

Comment: Just typing in your integral directly gives the solution for any `y`: `f[y_] :=1 - 0.121 (Sqrt[
     2 E \[Pi]] (-Erf[1/Sqrt[2] - Sqrt[y]] + 
       Erf[1/Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[y]]) + 
    4 Sinh[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[y]] (-Cosh[y] + Sinh[y]))`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I cannot reproduce the problem the user is experiencing;

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with the piece of code you provided. BTW, you can get the values of the expression involving the integral for varying the upper limit, like this,

```
Table[1 - 0.484*Integrate[E^(-x) Sinh[Sqrt[2 x]], {x, 0, y}], {y, 0, 0.5, 0.1}]
```

> {1., 0.986135, 0.962314, 0.93346, 0.901524, 0.867685}